# Obtener valor del idioma actual en web multilingüe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, idioma, traducción

El idioma lo cambio mediante URL de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="images/spainflag.png" onclick="spanish()" /> 
| 
<img src="images/ingflag.png" onclick="english()" />
```

Con el código Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      function english() {      
        window.location.href  = '?language=en';
      }
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
      function spanish() {      
        window.location.href  = '?language=es';
      }
</script>
```

Funciona perfectamente y los textos se me traducen como deberían pero cuando quiero obtener el valor del lenguaje actual no hallo la forma de hacerlo. He logrado obtener el valor del lenguaje del navegador y el del 'lang' del HTML, pero en el último caso siempre me devuelve 'en' dado que lo tengo puesto así por defecto en el header y no es el mismo atributo que el 'language' que se añade en el href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En JavaScript puedes leer el valor de los parámetros pasados por GET leyendo la propiedad `search` del objeto `window.location`. El valor devuelto por `window.location.search` será una cadena de texto con los valores que vengan tras el marca de interrogación (incluyendo el `?`).

Así, por ejemplo, si tu URL es así:

```
http://misitioweb.com?language=es
```

El valor de `window.location.search` será:

```
?language=es
```

Podrías crear un script más complejo que procese todos los parámetros ([puedes ver uno en esta respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5448595/3695983)), pero para lo que quieres parece que bastaría con una simple comparación:

```
// comprueba si el lenguaje seleccionado es español 
if (window.location.search == "?language=es") {
   // acciones a realizar si lenguaje fue cambiado a español
// si no, comprueba si el lenguaje seleccionado fue el inglés
} else if (window.location.search == "?language=en") {
   // acciones a realizar si lenguaje fue cambiado a inglés
}
```

---

Puedes guardar el idioma seleccionado en una cookie o en el LocalStorage para tenerlo disponible incluso en una página más adelante. Para ello podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
// el idioma por defecto será inglés, por ejemplo
var idioma = "en";

// comprueba si el lenguaje seleccionado es español 
if (window.location.search == "?language=es") {
   idioma = "es"
// si no, comprueba si ya existe uno de antes en el localstorage
} else if (localStorage.getItem("idioma")) {
   idioma = localStorage.getItem("idioma"); 
}

// guarda el idioma actual en el localStorage
localStorage.setItem("idioma", idioma);

// la variable idioma contendrá "es" o "en"
```

Comment: Eso funcionaría si el **?language=X** persistiera en todas las URL, pero solo aparece cuando cambio de idioma. Cuando voy a otra pantalla el valor se pierde(aunque la traducción persiste) y el _"window.location.search == "?language=X"_ me imprime un valor vacío.

Comment: @atila665 como parte de las acciones a realizar si el lenguaje cambia puedes guardar el valor en una cookie o en el LocalStorage y comprobarlo después si no se cambió el idioma. Voy a editar la respuesta para reflejarlo.

Comment: @atila665 añadí un nuevo script para guardar el idioma en el localStorage (parte del inglés como defecto para ahorrarme un condicional).

Comment: Vaya, bastante más fácil y obvio guardando una variable en el LocalStorage. Se me ocurrió crear una variable de sesión pero eso no se puede hacer desde JS, no había caído en esto. Gracias!